# display an image from a folder in google colaboratory

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

I'm able to display image from a specific folder when writing the python code in the cell, but have no idea how to display the image as running a python file.

I started working with google colaboratory. I'm able to display image from a specific folder when writing the python code in the cell, as below:

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = Image.open('path_of_image')
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im)
```

I want to save this code in a .py file, and when running the file, i want the image to be displayed in the cell.
For e.g., taking the file as demo.py and running the file

```
!python demo.py
```

Is this possible?

Comment: do you means folder on Google Colab or folder on your local computer? As I know Colab doesn't have access to folders on your computer. It may need to mount Google Drive and upload images on this drive.

Comment: after mounting the drive, folder in google colab.

Comment: if you run as `!python demo.py`  then you run it as normal script in separated process (outside Colab process) and it doesn't have access to Colab. You would have to `import` code like any other module - and then it would run in Colab and it would have access to cells.